# map not recognzing `.` or `.x` in its function

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, tidyverse, purrr

I'm wondering why `map` doesn't run on my reproducible example below?

```
library(purrr)
library(emmeans)
library(lme4)

dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/dat2.csv')

fit <- lmer(math ~ time*ses + I(time^2)*ses+ (time|id), data = dat)

map(0:7, 
         ~emtrends(fit, ~ses, var= "time", max.degree= 2,at =list(ses=0,time=.))) 
# I used .x also but didn't work

Error in ref_grid(object = object, max.degree = 2, at = list(ses = 0,  : 
  object '.' not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need only `map` :

```
library(emmeans)

purrr::map(0:7, 
     ~emtrends(fit, ~ses, var= "time", max.degree= 2,at =list(ses=0,time=.)))
```

and it seems to work if you pass `.x` in `imap` :

```
purrr::imap(0:7, 
       ~emtrends(fit, ~ses, var= "time", max.degree= 2,at =list(ses=0,time=.x)))
```

However, `imap` is used only when you want to pass name or index in the function. Here we don't need either of them so `map` should be enough.

Comment: This is very strange. Can you try `map` on the following as well: `library(lme4) ;
fit2 <- lmer(math ~ time*ses+I(time^2)*ses+ (time|id), data = dat)`

Comment: `purrr::map(0:7, ~emtrends(fit2, ~ses, var= "time", max.degree= 2,at =list(ses=0,time=.)))` seems to work for me.

Comment: Please see the error I get above! I know it has to do with `eval()`

Comment: This works for me so I don't think it has anything to do with `eval`. We need to figure out what is different between our packages/code. Did you try using `purrr::map` instead of just `map`? What is your `packageVersion('purrr')` ? Mine is `‘0.3.4’`

Comment: ‘0.3.4’, no it is not `purrr` the problem is `emmeans`

Comment: `packageVersion('emmeans')` is `‘1.5.2.1’`

Comment: mine is ‘1.4.6’

Comment: I also tried `lapply(0:7, function(i) emtrends(fit, ~ses, var= "time", max.degree= 2,at =list(ses=0,time=i)))` but the output doesn't make sense

Comment: Since the issue is with `emmeans` and not `map` I don't think changing `map` to `lapply` would make any difference. Did you try updating your package?

Comment: I'm reinstalling it, now.